# Cómo hago alguna condicional o evento para detectar cuando el usuario hace click en el botón de confirmar o cancelar ? Modal de Sweet Alert 2

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Estoy trabajando en la creación de dos modals usando la librería sweet alert 2. La idea original era lograr que estos modals se superpongan uno encima del otro, pero creo la librería no lo permite. Por tanto, quiero poner una condicional al segundo modal, que es el que ven en el código, para que cuando se de click en el botón de cancelar ocurra una cosa y cuando se de click en el botón de confirmar, ocurra otra. Cómo puedo lograr esto?

PD: Por cierto, ya hice una condicional (la que está al final del código), pero la consola del navegador me dice:

> ReferenceError: secondClick is not defined.

No sé si es que el modal 1 está haciendo interferencia con el modal 2 de alguna forma. Si necesitan el código del primer MODAL, me dicen.. Si por casualidad saben de alguna forma de crear modals superpuestos uno encima de otro, ya sea usando al menos bootstrap, igual se agradece. Gracias de antemano y SALUDOS :)

```js
$("body").on("click", "#divImage-steps", function() {

  // código que se ejecuta cuando se hace click en una imagen dentro de #divImage
  // alert("Se hizo click en una imagen dentro de #divImg");
  async function showAlert() {
    const {
      value: secondClick
    } = await Swal.fire({
      title: 'Nuevo Step',
      customClass: {
        popup: 'step-segundo-modal',
        title: 'step-title',
        confirmButton: 'step-confirm-button',
        cancelButton: 'story-cancel-button'
      },
      html: `<div class="input-group-text spanner float-left" style="height: 35px; max-width: 170px; margin-left: 70px; margin-right: -500px;">
                        <span>Intent:</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="dropdown" style="margin-top: 35px; margin-left: 30px;">
                       <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                         Seleccione
                       </button>
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                         <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button></li>
                         <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button></li>
                         <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button></li>
                       </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="input-group-text spanner float-left" style="height: 35px; max-width: 170px; margin-left: 70px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: -500px;">
                        <span>Action:</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="dropdown" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 35px;">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Seleccione
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button></li>
                            <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button></li>
                            <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="input-group-text spanner float-left" style="height: 35px; max-width: 170px; margin-left: 70px; margin-right: -70px;">
                        <span>Id de mensaje:</span>
                     </div>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary search-button" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Buscar por ID</button>
                    `,
      confirmButtonText: 'Crear',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
      showCancelButton: true
    });
  }

  if (secondClick) {
    // Se hizo clic en el botón de confirmar
    Swal.fire({
      position: 'center',
      icon: 'success',
      title: 'Step creado con éxito!',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    });

    // Aquí puedes realizar las acciones que deseas cuando se confirma el paso
    // ...
  } else {
    // Se hizo clic en el botón de cancelar
    Swal.fire({
      position: 'center',
      icon: 'warning',
      title: 'Step cancelado con éxito!',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    });
  }

  showAlert();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<img id="divImage-steps" src="" alt="imagen dentro de #divImage">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solucion con ayuda de un bot de IA. Aqui la dejo para los que intenten hacer lo mismo y no encuentren como:

```js
$("body").on("click", "#divImage-steps", function() {
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Nuevo Step',
        customClass: {
          popup: 'step-segundo-modal',
          title: 'step-title',
          confirmButton: 'step-confirm-button',
          cancelButton: 'story-cancel-button'
        },
        html: `<div class="input-group-text spanner float-left" style="height: 35px; max-width: 170px; margin-left: 70px; margin-right: -500px;">
                      <span>Intent:</span>
                   </div>
                   <div class="dropdown" style="margin-top: 35px; margin-left: 30px;">
                     <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                       Seleccione
                     </button>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                       <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button></li>
                       <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button></li>
                       <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button></li>
                     </ul>
                   </div>
                   <div class="input-group-text spanner float-left" style="height: 35px; max-width: 170px; margin-left: 70px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: -500px;">
                      <span>Action:</span>
                   </div>
                   <div class="dropdown" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 35px;">
                      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                          Seleccione
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button></li>
                          <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button></li>
                          <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button></li>
                      </ul>
                   </div>
                   <div class="input-group-text spanner float-left" style="height: 35px; max-width: 170px; margin-left: 70px; margin-right: -70px;">
                      <span>Id de mensaje:</span>
                   </div>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary search-button" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Buscar por ID</button>
                  `,
        confirmButtonText: 'Crear',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        showCancelButton: true
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {

          // Se hizo clic en el botón de confirmar
          Swal.fire({
            position: 'center',
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Step creado con éxito!',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
          });
        } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
          // Se hizo clic en el botón de cancelar
          Swal.fire({
            position: 'center',
            icon: 'warning',
            title: 'Step cancelado con éxito!',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
          });
        }
      });
       

  showAlert();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<img id="divImage-steps" src="" alt="imagen dentro de #divImage">
```